# The minimum corner of the box must be less than or equal to maximum corner

Tags: ogre, gazebo-9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I encountered very strange behavior of Gazebo. I have the very simplest XACRO file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<robot name="car" xmlns:xacro="http://ros.org/wiki/xacro">

    <link name="base">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <!--<box size="0.6 0.1 0.2" />-->
                <cylinder length="0.6" radius="0.2"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0" />
        </visual>

        <collision>
            <geometry>
                <!--<box size="0.6 0.1 0.2" />-->
                <cylinder length="0.6" radius="0.2"/>
            </geometry>

            <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0" />
        </collision>
    </link>

</robot>
```

Launch file:

```
<launch>
    <arg name="limited" default="false"/>
    <arg name="paused" default="false"/>
    <arg name="gui" default="true"/>

    <!-- startup simulated world -->
    <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
        <arg name="world_name" default="$(find car_gazebo)/worlds/simple_world.world"/>
        <arg name="paused" value="$(arg paused)"/>
        <arg name="gui" value="$(arg gui)"/>
    </include>

    <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro --inorder '$(find car_gazebo)/urdf/car.urdf.xacro'" />

    <!-- push robot_description to factory and spawn robot in gazebo -->
    <node name="spawn_gazebo_model" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" args="-urdf -param robot_description -model car" respawn="false" output="screen" />

</launch>
```

And there is no any primitives drawn despite the fact that I get message about successful spawning:
`Spawn status: SpawnModel: Successfully spawned entity`. Moreover clicking on `car` model in `models` tab in Gazebo leads to an Ogre crash with the following error:

`gzclient: /build/ogre-1.9-B6QkmW/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/OgreMain/include/OgreAxisAlignedBox.h:252: void Ogre::AxisAlignedBox::setExtents(const Ogre::Vector3&, const Ogre::Vector3&): Assertion (min.x <= max.x && min.y <= max.y && min.z <= max.z) && "The minimum corner of the box must be less than or equal to maximum corner" failed`

Has someone ever faced the same issue? I use Gazebo 9.0.0.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/21441/the-minimum-corner-of-the-box-must-be-less-than-or-equal-to-maximum-corner/) by [nameofuser1](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4279/nameofuser1/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-12-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I suspect this may have been solved by [this recent pull request](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/pull-requests/3033/fix-model-bounding-box/diff) and will be released soon on Gazebo 9.15.0.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2018-12-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0